# Ionic Input Box Width

Tags: ionic-framework

i have a problem with the input from ionic framework. input seem to fit to mobile device / small screen device, it cannot stretch to fit to medium or large device view port. is it deliberately or a bug there? and how make it fit to any screen at least to medium screen as i am writing an apps for tablet or ipad.

this [pen](http://codepen.io/ssktanaka/pen/JdqBvp?editors=101) explained the case, try to type along words / sentences in the your own content box.

**input code**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your own content" ng-model="customQuote" required>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you find the bug. You should patch ionic.css:

```
.item-input-inset .item-input-wrapper input {
    padding-left: 4px;
    height: 29px;
    background: transparent;
    line-height: 18px;
    // you should add the following:
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

or make your own style and add to your input